# Can I use citation of used machine learning methods from O'reilly?

Tags: citations, reference-request, machine-learning

I would like to describe my used machine learning methods in the methodology of my thesis and my source is **Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras & TensorFlow** from O´Reilly. I anticipate that there is no general answer and it depends on the University, however, if I would like to publish it as a scientific paper, are there any obstacles with these sources?

Many thanks

Comment: Btw There are many citations inside the book on scientific papers in the case of concrete methods...

Comment: Why would there be an issue with using this book?

Comment: Maybe because It is not from the scientific publisher? e.g. Springer, Taylor and Francis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at Google Scholar, you can see that there are, at the time of writing, [3420 citations](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=8615696746315241538&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en) to the book you are referring to. So yes, since you used that book as a source for your methods, do add the citation. There is nothing inherently wrong with O'Reilly books, when you use them for your research, you cite them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should cite this book, and also find the original academic publications about the methods, and read and cite them.

Or maybe not the original academic publications, but some major academic publication such as an academic book that describes them, for example: Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman (2009), The Elements of Statistical Learning. [https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/ElemStatLearn/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should cite it as you would any source. There are two reasons. If you don't cite it you may give the impression that you developed the techniques yourself, which is plagiarism. Also, a reader needs full context of your work and some of that appears in the book.

Unless something is *common knowledge* it needs to be cited. Things in undergraduate textbooks are usually common knowledge, and this may be in a grey area, but it is better to cite for the context reason if nothing else.

And an unneeded citation is almost never harmful, while a missing one, if needed, always is.